# Importing Custom Module In Django "No Module Named custom_module" Error

Tags: python, django, path, virtualenv, wsgi

I wrote a simple module which I need to import into my Django settings file.

The importation occurs in the following section in the `libraries` dictionary:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),

            #re-route the search for templates into this custom template directory
            os.path.join(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), 'tshirt-theme'),

            #Uncomment the line below to restore the original Oscar template
            #OSCAR_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR,
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

                'oscar.apps.search.context_processors.search_form',
                'oscar.apps.promotions.context_processors.promotions',
                'oscar.apps.checkout.context_processors.checkout',
                'oscar.apps.customer.notifications.context_processors.notifications',
                'oscar.core.context_processors.metadata',
            ],
            'libraries': {
                'promotion_tags': 'custom_oscar.templatetags.promotion_tags'
            }
        },
    },
]
```

The trouble is that I get an error. Here it is:

> InvalidTemplateLibrary at /
>
> Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to
>   load 'custom_oscar.templatetags.promotion_tags': No module named
>   custom_oscar.templatetags.promotion_tags

The code works on my local machine, but fails when I migrate it to production (Ubuntu 16.01).

The structure of my project is as follows:

```
/var/www/vhosts/book/
  ...book-site
          custom_oscar
               templatetags
                    promotion_tags.py
          manage.py
          book
              settings.py
              wsgi.py
     ..
  ...book-env
          bin
```

Initially I suspected that the problem may be with the path, so I checked the trace, and the correct path seems to be included:

Python Path:

```
['/var/www/vhosts/book/book-site',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/var/www/vhosts/book/book-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
```

Could anyone tell me why this error occurs? How can I fix it?

P.S. If it helps, I can successfully import this module from the command line, when I manually activate the virtualenv.

Comment: According your description, I suspect either your `wsgi.py` or your production WSGI engine (which is ?) settings.

Comment: Are there `__init__.py` files in the directories ?

Comment: @SachinKukreja There aren't. I tried adding them on the production side and it is making a difference. Why would it work without those files on my local machine?